# Angular 5 - Can't get assign the class property

Tags: javascript, json, angular, api, typescript

There are a list of products listed from json and i placed the **BUY** button assigned with the ID of the corresponding product. when i press the **Buy** button order should be placed. I can able to bind the data to the property (***prodID***) but i can't able to assign the variable prodID in the array ***body[ ]***. I can't able to place order using json since prod id is required which i can't assign it properly

Here is my code
**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Woocommerce } from './Woocommerce';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  result: any ;
  prodID: number;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient ){ }
  baseURL = 'https://wc.example.com/wp-json/wc/v2';
  products = 'products';
  consumer_key = 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  consumer_secret = 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  body = {
    payment_method: 'paypal',
    payment_method_title: 'Direct Bank Transfer',
    set_paid: true,
    line_items: [
      {
        product_id: this.prodID,
        quantity: 1
      }
    ]
  };
  getProductDetails(){
    this.http.get<Woocommerce>(`${this.baseURL}/${this.products}?consumer_key=${this.consumer_key}&consumer_secret=${this.consumer_secret}`).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.result = data;
        console.log(this.result);
      });
  }
  buyNow(getID: any) {
      this.prodID = getID;
    this.http.post<Woocommerce>(`${this.baseURL}/orders?consumer_key=${this.consumer_key}&consumer_secret=${this.consumer_secret}`, this.body, {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json' ),
      }
    ).subscribe(resp => {console.log(resp);});
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getProductDetails();
  }
}
```

And **app.component.html**

```html
<h1>Woocommerce</h1>
<form>
  <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
  <tr>
    <td scope="col">ID</td>
    <td scope="col">Name</td>
    <td scope="col">Price</td>
    <td scope="col">Product Image</td>
    <td scope="col">Buy</td>
  </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let r of result" [attr.id]="r.id">
    <td >{{r.id}}</td>
    <td>{{r.name}}</td>
    <td>{{r.price}}</td>
    <span *ngFor="let k of r.images">
    <td><img height="100" width="100"  src={{k.src}}></td></span>
    <td><button type="button" [attr.id]="r.id" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="buyNow(r.id)">Buy now</button></td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it just create a copy of the initial state for body variable , so it will always return undefined.

Here is the solution how you can do that

```
getBody(){
    return {
        payment_method: 'paypal',
        payment_method_title: 'Direct Bank Transfer',
        set_paid: true,
        line_items: [
        {
            product_id: this.prodID,
            quantity: 1
        }
        ]
    };
}

buyNow(getID: any) {
    this.prodID = getID;
    this.http.post<Woocommerce>(`${this.baseURL}/orders?consumer_key=${this.consumer_key}&consumer_secret=${this.consumer_secret}`, this.getBody(), {
        headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json' ),
      }
    ).subscribe(resp => {console.log(resp);});
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to separate into two components like list products in one component and buying the product in another.???

Comment: @PrakashGD, yes you can do that, for that you need to create a common service and use that in those components.